# Lazy loading huge json data in polymer

Tags: json, polymer, lazy-loading

I have a JSON file that contains a large amount of data that causes the HTML page to become unresponsive when iterating over it.

I am using Polymer and iterating over the JSON data inside a template.

Is there a way that I can do the iteration using lazy loading so that I do not have to load all the data at the same time?

Below is my HTML file for the element.

```
<polymer-element name="flash-card">
  <template id="k">
    <style>
      flip-card {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
      }
    </style>
    <core-ajax id='ajaxCard'
      url='../api/gre_questions.json'
      on-core-response="{{onResponse}}"
      handleAs='json'></core-ajax>

    <div horizontal layout wrap style="width: 100%">
      <template repeat="{{words in json}}">

        <flip-card axis="y" class="flip-card">

          <front style="background:#232343">
            <div style="overflow:hidden">{{words.word}}</div>
          </front>
          <back>
            <div style="overflow:hidden">
              {{words.meaning}}
            </div>
          </back>
        </flip-card>
      </template>
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer("flash-card",{
      json: null,
      ready: function () {
        this.$.ajaxCard.go();
      },
      onResponse: function (e, detail, sender) {
        this.json = detail.response;
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: Have a look at the `core-list` element here. From the docs: _For performance reasons, not every item in the list is rendered at once; instead a small subset of actual template elements (enough to fill the viewport) are rendered and reused as the user scrolls._

Comment: @BenThomas the issue is that now that im using iron elements its inferring with my core elements which cannot be used along with the iron elements and leaving the page unreadable.

Comment: I made a mistake in my initial comment. I thought you were using Polymer 1.0 and you appear to be using 0.5(ish). In this previous version of Polymer, the `iron-list` was actually the `core-list`.

Comment: Yes I replaced it with that earlier and it worked and the response time is quite good! :)

Comment: another one doubt is that i heard in some polymer tut video that we can port 0.5 to 1.0 but couldnt get exactly how to do it can u help me out with that?

Comment: Start off with this [migration guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html) and look [here](https://elements.polymer-project.org/) for the new Polymer 1.0 elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<core-ajax id='ajaxCard' url='../api/gre_questions.json' on-core-response="{{onResponse}}" handleAs='json' ></core-ajax>
<core-list data="{{json}}" style="width:100%; height: 100%">
  <template>
    <div >
      <button></button>
      <core-collapse>
        <div class="collapse-content">
          {{model.word}} : {{model.meaning}}
        </div>
      </core-collapse>
    </div>
  </template>
</core-list>
```